# Apache Arrow Java API Documentation

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I am looking for useful documentations or examples for the Apache Arrow API. Can anyone point to some useful resources? I was only able to find some blogs and JAVA documentation (which doesn't say much).

From what I read, it is a standard in-memory columnar database for fast analytics. Is it possible to load the data to arrow memory and to manipulate it ?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

You should use arrow as a middle man between two applications which need to communicate using passing objects.

> Arrow isn’t a standalone piece of software but rather a component used
>   to accelerate analytics within a particular system and to allow
>   Arrow-enabled systems to exchange data with low overhead.

For example Arrow improves the performance for data movement within a [cluster](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/02/introducing-apache-arrow-a-fast-interoperable-in-memory-columnar-data-structure-standard/).

See [tests](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/java/tools/src/test/java/org/apache/arrow/tools/TestFileRoundtrip.java) for examples.

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    File testInFile = testFolder.newFile("testIn.arrow");
    File testOutFile = testFolder.newFile("testOut.arrow");

    writeInput(testInFile, allocator);

    String[] args = {"-i", testInFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-o", testOutFile.getAbsolutePath()};
    int result = new FileRoundtrip(System.out, System.err).run(args);
    assertEquals(0, result);

    validateOutput(testOutFile, allocator);
}
```

Also [Apache Parquet](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/70f28810a5547219e18ffc3465f519c454fee6e5/parquet-arrow/src/test/java/org/apache/parquet/arrow/schema/TestSchemaConverter.java) uses it. There are conversion examples from/to arrow objects:

```
MessageType parquet = converter.fromArrow(allTypesArrowSchema).getParquetSchema();

Schema arrow = converter.fromParquet(supportedTypesParquetSchema).getArrowSchema();
```

Comment: The linked test example isn't very informative.  It isn't immediately obvious what a `BufferAllocator` or `RootAllocator` is.  There isn't any evidence of "manipulating data" either...

Comment: The converter included in Parquet's github repo seems to rely on Arrow 0.1.0 (and I can't get it to work, I get ClassNotFoundException when doing `new SchemaConverter()`, though I may be doing something wrong when installing it, as I could not find any published artifact for parquet-arrow)

Answer (score 0):

They have some basic [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/) on how to use Apache Arrow on their site now. Although it could use a bit of filling out.